# $f,g$ are measurable functions. Why is $\{x: f(x)>g(x)\}$ a measurable set?

Tags: measure-theory

This comes from the last part of [this section of a wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#For_finite_measures).

A set is measurable if it's part of the domain's $\sigma$-algebra. Why should this set be in the domain's $\sigma$-algebra, which we don't know anything about?

Comment: Try to prove that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable, so is $h:= f-g$. Then the set you're looking for is $h^{-1}\left((0,\infty]\right)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\{x:f(x)>g(x)\}=(f-g)^{-1}((0,+\infty))$.

$f-g$ is measurable, $(0,+\infty)$ is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, so by definition of a measurable function, $(f-g)^{-1}((0,+\infty))$ is a measurable set.

Answer (score 4):

Alternate approach.
$$
\{x: f(x)>g(x)\} = \bigcup_r \left(\{x: f(x)>r\} \cap \{x: r>g(x)\} \right)
$$
where the union is over all rational numbers $r$.